# how to detect if child window has been submitted using javascript?

Tags: php, javascript

i have a child window whereby it contains the twitter sharing page... how to detect if the twitter sharing form has been submitted to twitter? note: this is a child window..

because I want to show an alert box after the sharing window closes
`twitter sharing submit detection`

```
var myWindow;
    function openTwitterWindow(url){
    var width=550;var height=425;var left=parseInt((screen.availWidth/2)-(width/2));
    var top=parseInt((screen.availHeight/2)-(height/2));
    var windowFeatures="width="+width+",height="+height+",status,resizable,left="+left+",top="+top+"screenX="+left+",screenY="+top;
    myWindow=window.open(url,"subWind",windowFeatures);
    jQuery('form#update-form').submit(function(){
        onWindowClose(myWindow, myCallback);
    });
   }


    function myCallback() {
        alert("Your message has been shared. Thank you");
    }   

    function onWindowClose(windowRef,callback, period) {
        period = period || 20;
        setTimeout(function check() {
            if(windowRef == null || windowRef.closed) {
                callback();
            } else {
                setTimeout(check, period);
            }
        }, period);
    }
```

THAT CODE ABOVE IS WRONG...I NEED HELP

```
<a style="cursor: pointer" onclick="openTwitterWindow('https://twitter.com/share?url=<?php echo $url; ?>&text= and so on and so forth...
```

Comment: `detect if the twitter sharing form has been submitted to twitter` can't

Comment: what's the best solution here ? ...because when I close the window by clicking the x button, it will pop my alert box, the only way i can think of to avoid this is by detecting the submission of the twitter share and only after that will pop the alert

Comment: Please show some code. I don't think it's possible to detect if an form on another page has been submitted.

Comment: do the submission via `ajax` and put your code inside the `success`

Comment: twitter is twitter..how am i gonna put that thing in ajax..twitter provides that share url

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
var child = window.open('urlofchild');
var closetime = setInterval(checkChildClose, 500);

function checkChildClose() {
    if (child.closed) {
        alert("Child window closed");   
        clearInterval(closetime);
    }
}
```

Comment: that would only run once, don't you need to schedule the re-runs

Comment: what if the child window was closed by the user and didn't even clicked the submit button to share the post to twitter?

Comment: @sasori there's no way to find out, unless Twitter offers an API just for that. LOok up "same-origin policy"

Comment: if there's no way to find that out, any ideas for a work around of this problem? ...because if am gonna pop an alert box when the child window got closed without even submitting the twitter share thing, it doesn't look right

Answer (score 0):

Usually, when I design 'child' windows I use CSS and do virtual windows. Then you have all the information you need within a page. Then, you can use AJAX and JSON to work with the data.

Demo: http://www.codesoaked.com/demo/css-popup-window.html#

Comment: But then you still have the problem of detecting what happens inside a cross-domain iframe. Virtual windows won't help you here.